# Check current SVN repository version

Tags: svn

I'm trying to figure out, how to get the current SVN repository version but with no luck.

When I try with:

```
svn info -r BASE
```

I get following information:

```
Path: foo-svn
URL: file:///home/hsz/Project/foo-svn
Relative URL: ^/
Repository Root: file:///home/hsz/Project/foo-svn
Repository UUID: b5555486-2e29-45ed-a0bb-b925095964a9
Revision: 10
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: hsz
Last Changed Rev: 10
Last Changed Date: 2015-05-28 11:26:50 +0200 (Thu, 28 May 2015)
```

So there is a lot useless information around it. Also it varies depending on the machine language (english can be forced prepending command with `LANG=en_US`).

But the real problem is when I commit something. The output of:

```
svn commit -m "foo"
```

is:

```
Committed revision 11.
```

But `svn info` still shows information about the revision `10`. After updating the project it is the valid version.

Is there any way to obtain the current real version number without updating the whole project ?

**edit** more complex example:

- User A calls `svn update` and gets the latest version of the project: `r10`,
- User A commits new change which is noted as `r11`,
- User B updates the project and commits next change: `r12`,
- User A needs to know if there is any changes in the repository without updating the project, so he calls:

  svn log BASE:HEAD

but it shows too much output:

```
r10
r11
r12
```

instead of:

```
r11
r12
```

because `BASE` is `r10` instead of `r11` which was HIS last commit.

Is it possible to get the number of the CURRENT revision in the local copy ? In this case, after the update and commit it is `r11`.

Only **svn** command is supported and no `svn update` allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Updates and commits in Subversion are separate](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs)! That's why `svn info` shows `10` after you commit.
- I guess that you actually want to use [`svnversion` tool.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html) Try `svnversion -c`.
- You can also run `svn update` and check the last line that always says `At revision REVNUM`.

Comment: `svnversion` looks nice, but I have only access to the `svn` command (I mean, I have the `svn` executable absolute path that I call and cannot obtain path to other binaries).

Comment: @hsz using `svnversion` is the preferred approach. However, you can also run `svn update` and check the last line that always says `At revision N.`

Comment: Updating the project is not acceptable - I just want to notify the user that he's an incoming update pending.

Comment: @hsz describe what exactly you need in your question. Now I can recommend `svn status --show-updates --verbose`.

Comment: As I wrote - I need the current local version number. After update we get number `x`, when we commit something it gets `x+1`. So I expect this `x+1` number, instead of `x` which is returned by `svn log`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the latest revision number of your repo without updating local copy first, use `-r HEAD`:

```
svn info -r HEAD
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to know the **current** local revision number after commit performing.

Answer (score 0):

svn info --show-item revision -r COMMITTED